# html() not updated before alert() is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I've got a problem since I've migrated from jQuery 1.11 to jQuery 3.0. I'm running a jQuery POST request and before the migration it first finished the `html(data.responseText)` and then moved on with the code that follows. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/files/" + url,
    data: $("#entryForm").serialize() + '&journal_id=' + journalId,
    complete: function(data) {
        $('#saveResults').html(data.responseText);
        alert("function done");
    }
});
```

In the data.responseText there is an `alert` which runs first and after complete the function `html()` the other `alert("function done")` was running.

After the migration the `alert("function done")` is running first so it appears the function `html()` is not finished at this point because the alert from the responseText is coming after the `alert("function done")`. So I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/files/" + url,
    data: $("#entryForm").serialize() + '&journal_id=' + journalId,
    complete: function(data) {
        $('#saveResults').html(data.responseText).promise().done(function() {
            alert("function done");
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this didn't fix my problem. Anyone an idea how to fix it?

Comment: The problem sounds very odd as `html()` is synchronous (which is why your second attempt doesn't work) so should complete before the `alert()` is shown. I can only assume it's an inconsistency with the browser renderer where the Ui doesn't get updated immediately with the DOM and the `alert()` blocks the thread. You could try putting the `alert()` in a `setTimeout()` call with a short timeout, say 10ms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery event after html() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826484/jquery-event-after-html-function)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Remember that jQuery handles `<script>` tags in `.html()` specially, because assigning to `.innerHTML` doesn't execute them. I suspect they changed how this worked between versions, and the new method is asynchronous.

Comment: @Barmar I guess you are right and it could be to avoid sync warning regarding any script handled by `html()` method, as on older jq version.

Comment: You might want to ask this question in the jQuery Forum. You're more likely to find someone with intimate knowledge of the internals, and how they changed between releases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

.html is set when response is back and when success is completed, complete is ran

```
success: function(data){
    $('#saveResults').html(data.responseText);
},
complete: function(data)
{
    alert("function done");
}
```